# How to have a unique icon for two screens with react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a bottom tab navigator in react native and I put my screens into it this way :

```
const AppStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        FirstPage : {
            screen: FirstPage,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarVisible: true,
            }
        },
        SecondPage : {
            screen: SecondPage,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarVisible: true,
                tabBarButtonComponent: () => false
            }
        },
        ThirdPage : {
            screen: ThirdPage,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarVisible: true,
            }
        },
    },
    {
        defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
                if (navigation.state.routeName === 'FirstPage' || navigation.state.routeName === 'SecondPage') {
                    icon = focused ? require('iconPathFocused.png') : require('iconPathNotFocused.png)
                } else if (navigation.state.routeName === 'ThirdPage') {
                    [...]
                }

                return <TabIcon path={icon}/>
            }
        })
    }
)
```

The problem is that when I'm on the SecondPage screen, the tabbar is still visible but none of the icons are "hilighted" because not focused.

The thing is I don't want any particular icon to be displayed for the second page. I want it to be like a child of the First page so when I navigate from the First page to the Second one, the same icon (still FirstPage's one so) is displayed and highlighted.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

You can set `navigationOptions` something like this with `tabBarIcon` for all your screens

So you can set different focused and not focused icons for each and every tab.

```
FirstPage : {
    screen: FirstPage,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "First Page",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
            <Image source={focused ? require('iconPathFocused.png') : require('iconPathNotFocused.png')} style={{height: 28, width: 28}}/>
        ),
    }
},
SecondPage : {
    screen: SecondPage,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Second Page",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
            <Image source={focused ? require('iconPathFocused.png') : require('iconPathNotFocused.png')} style={{height: 28, width: 28}}/>
        ),
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to bellow **defaultNavigationOptions**

```
 tabBarOptions: {
          activeTintColor: 'tomato',
          inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        }
```

this might help.
For more details have help from React-navigation official page : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html

Check customise appearance there that might help further.